# Need to merge multiple hive partitions into one partition in spark

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-partitions

I have around 50 partitions in hive table. I need to merge each set of partitions into one partition. I tried to use rename partition command. But getting error message.

Need help in merging multiple hive partitions into one partition in spark

```
 ALTER TABLE db.table PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='segment_id:1|process_date:20220417') RENAME TO PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='process_date:20220417')

 ALTER TABLE db.table PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='segment_id:3|process_date:20220417') RENAME TO PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='process_date:20220417')

 ALTER TABLE db.table PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='segment_id:4|process_date:20220417') RENAME TO PARTITION (appname='SCORING',indicator='process_date:20220417')
```

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to rename partition. Partition already exists:db.table

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  puting all the data into one partition will remove a lot of concurrency, so why do you want to do that?  This sounds like an XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I found an another way to achieve the required output. Inserting into different table and dropping the partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a [sql statement `distribute by`.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-distribute-by.html#description)

In spark programmign language there are more tools to change the partitions.

You can use [partitionby](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning) to repartition in spark.

or you could write a select to grab the partitioned data.  Then you can use [coalece or repartition](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce/) to create 1 partition.